Windows 7 "repair your computer" option not showing virtualbox
I installed windows 7 inside the virtualbox, I want to boot windows into the repair mode I tired pressing F8 during the booting process but that didn't work I also directly turned off my operating system thinking that when I re-boot it the I will get an option like "repair my computer" but I only got "boot in safe mode" "boot into cmd" how can I get the option to repair my computer.

What you want requires the WinRE partition to exist, it might not exist, depending on the image configuration you used to install Windows
